# ASP.NET: Problems with referencing a user control in another user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having problems in a usecontrol referencing a other usercontrol:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class includes_EnquiryRssButton : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    public includes_EnquirySearchForm EnquirySearchForm { get; set; } //compile error

    ...

}
```

I get a compile error saying that type of namespace can't be found. The annoying part is that I think I had it working earlier.

Comment: Where's includes_EnquirySearchForm defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding:

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish it by converting a "Web Site" project to a "Web Application" project.